# looping through multiple collections at the same time

Tags: laravel

I have seen this question asked a few times and in each case its not clear what the solution is.

I need to loop through 2 collections  one contains employees info the other contains bookings of these employees

Im reluctant to use a nested for loop if a nested for loop will mean the operation will first loop through  the inner loop  till done and repeats each time  the outer loop increments

```
@foreach($Employees as $Employee, $bookings as $booking)
        // return somethuing
@endforeach
```

Comment: you can check inside of the loop something like this `if($Employee['id'] === $booking['employee_id'] )` this will gives you only results you want based on condition

Comment: @ViperTecPro Great solution thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query `Booking` such that the results are indexed by `employee_id`

Assuming you have multiple `bookings` for each `employee`.

```
$employees = Employee::get();
$bookings = Booking::get();
$bookings = collect($bookings)->groupBy('employee_id');

@foreach($employees as $employee)
    @if(isset($bookings[$employee->id]))
        @foreach($bookings[$employee->id] as $booking)
            //you can get all the bookings of each employee

        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

If each `employee` has a single `booking`:

```
$employees = Employee::get();
$bookings = Booking::get()->keyBy('employee_id');

@foreach($employees as $employee)
    @if(isset($bookings[$employee->id]))
        //you can get the booking of each employee

    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make relationship between the Employee and Booking like Employee has many bookings. Read **Laravel Relationship** in official ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)).

And then in your **controller** you can fetch the employee with it's bookings. Like this:

```
$Employees = Employee::with('bookings')->get();
// here is try to make your own query.

return view('your_view', compact('Employees'));
```

And In your **blade**:

```
@foreach($Employees as $Employee)
    @foreach($Employee->bookings as $booking)
        {{ $booking }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I hope it would helpful.

Comment: Its not the same count, $bookings is always less or equal to $Employees

Comment: Employee collection:
```

Collection {#182 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => Employee {#185 ▶}
    1 => Employee {#186 ▶}
    2 => Employee {#187 ▶}
    3 => Employee {#188 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Booking Collection:
```

Collection {#177 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Bookings {#192 ▶}
    1 => Bookings {#193 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: try to make relationship between employee and booking..... https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships